# Stop executing code when return null on Page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that has a few properties in the .cs,
Those properties are then later on used in the .aspx
For instance:

.CS

```
public string Person { get;set; }
```

.ASPX

```
<a href="<%= Person.WebSite %> >My website</a>
```

The problem is here that if Person is null, the framework will still try to run the .aspx and will end up throwing a null-exception..
and if I make a simple check in my Page_Load

if(Person == null)
      return

It would still try to execute the .ASPX, which then would again throw an exception

So.. my question is.. is there anyway to prevent the .ASPX from getting loaded if Persons is null

```
if(Person == null)
 //Dont run the aspx,code
 Response.Write("Something went wrong!");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can write code like this :

```
<a href="<%= Person != null? Person.WebSite : null %> >My website</a>
```

But this will results in producing an unclickable link. Which is propably not desired, isn't it?

But such requirements are often far more easier to fulfill using databinding. ASP.Net has been design to mimic Windows Forms behavior. What you are doing here, is "legacy" asp code-style, writing in the html stream. There are some case when it's legitimate, but it's not usual.

Comment: `<a href='<%= Person != null? Person.WebSite : null %>' <%= Person != null? "onclick='alert('no data..')'" : "" %>>My website</a>`